# Django c2dm with OAuth2

Tags: django, oauth, android-c2dm, credentials

I want to develop a Django application to send message thr google c2dm server to andriod device.it uses OAuth2 to authorization.
    first i got the credentials and store it in the storage as storage and then i want to get the credentials from
    storage and send this credentials together other params and headers to c2dm api.
    i could get the credentials for scope https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm and store it in storage.
    please some one guide me,how can i make the request with credentials and send to https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send to deliver.
    Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you've been able to perform step 2 *Exchange authorization code for tokens* on [Google OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/). Then you should have acquired a **refresh token** and an **access token** (if you didn't receive a refresh token, verify that you have checked **Force approval prompt** and selected **offline** for *Access type* in the *OAuth 2.0 Configuration*.

The access token will expire after some time (usually 1 hour), but the refresh token does not. The refresh token (together with the **OAuth Client ID** and the **OAuth Client secret**) can be used to obtain a new access token:

```
curl --data-urlencode "client_id=OAuthClientID"
     --data-urlencode "client_secret=OAuthClientSecret"
     --data-urlencode "refresh_token=RefreshToken"
     -d "grant_type=refresh_token" "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
```

(Replace OAuthClientID, OAuthClientSecret, RefreshToken). For futher reading refer to: [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications - Offline Access](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)

Now you can use this access token and the registration ID of the device to send messages to that device using C2DM:

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer AccessToken"
     --data-urlencode "registration_id=RegistrationID"
     --data-urlencode "collapse_key=0"
     --data-urlencode "data.message=YourMessage"
     "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send"
```

(Replace AccessToken, RegistrationID and YourMessage)